# Notation for $f(n) = \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, notation

Is there any sort of standard notation for the value represented by $f(n) = \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$, where $\Lambda(n)$ is the Mangoldt function?  So essentially a function that is $\frac {1}{a}$ when $n$ is equal to some prime $p$ to the power of $a$, and 0 otherwise.

And while on the subject, is there any consensus about notation for its summatory function, which is also equal to $\pi(n) + \frac{1}{2}\pi(n^\frac{1}{2})+ \frac{1}{3}\pi(n^\frac{1}{3})+\cdots$, where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function?  Riemann called it $f(n)$, I believe, Edwards calls it $J(n)$, Crandall and Pomerance seem to refer to it as $\pi^*(n)$, and I've found several other references that refer to it as $\Pi(n)$.  I feel like I've seen $\Pi(n)$ more often, but not enough to feel confident...

Comment: On the second question I've seen $\pi^*(n)$ most often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bateman and Diamond, Analytic Number Theory, use $\kappa(n)$ for the function in your title (page 28), but I don't know that I'd call it standard. They use $\Pi$ for the summatory function (page 218).

Jameson, The Prime Number Theorem, uses $c(n)$ for the function in the title, but I think that's only in an exercise on page 81. In the same exercise, he uses $\Pi$ for the summatory function.

Stopple, A Primer of Analytic Number Theory, also uses $\Pi$ for the summatory function. Ditto Montgomery and Vaughan, Multiplicative Number Theory, page 416.

Davenport, Multiplicative Number Theory, page 112, calls the summatory function $\pi_1$.

Comment: So it would probably be fair to say that $\Pi(n)$ is relatively standard notation (though not on par with, say, $\Lambda(n)$ for the Mangoldt function), and that the function in my title simply doesn't have any kind of standard notation.  I just remembered that Iwaniec and Kowalski refer to it as $\Lambda'(n)$, perhaps bolstering the idea that there is no standard.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't expect readers to know what $\Pi(n)$ is without giving them a definition.